# Python: List appending issue

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I am having a logical error of sorts and I can not seem to pick it out.  Here is what I have:

```
Document = 'Sample1'
locationslist = []
thedictionary = []
userword = ['the', 'a']
filename = 'Sample1'
for inneritem in userword:
     thedictionary.append((inneritem,locationslist))
     for position, item in enumerate(file_contents): 
        if item == inneritem:
            locationslist.append(position)
wordlist = (thedictionary, Document)
print wordlist
```

So basically I am trying to create a larger list (thedictionary) from a smaller list (locationslist) together with the particular userword.  I almost have it except I have that the output is putting all the locations of all the words (in which there are only 2 - `'the'` and `'a'`) in each of the lists.  Seems like there is a simple logic problem - but I can't seem to spot it.  The output is:

```
([('the', [5, 28, 41, 97, 107, 113, 120, 138, 141, 161, 2, 49, 57, 131, 167, 189, 194, 207, 215, 224]), 
  ('a', [5, 28, 41, 97, 107, 113, 120, 138, 141, 161, 2, 49, 57, 131, 167, 189, 194, 207, 215, 224])], 
 'Sample1')
```

But should be:

```
([('the', [5, 28, 41, 97, 107, 113, 120, 138, 141, 161]), 
  ('a', [2, 49, 57, 131, 167, 189, 194, 207, 215, 224])], 
 'Sample1')
```

See how both position lists are being appended to each of the problematic output concerning each of the userwords `'the'` and `'a'`?  I could use advice on what I am doing wrong here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only create one `locationslist`, so you only have one.  It is shared by both words.  You need to create a new `locationslist` on each loop iteration:

```
for inneritem in userword:
    locationslist = []
    thedictionary.append((inneritem,locationslist))
    # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn.. sometimes it is those little fixes unseen that just make you want to give yourself a pile-driver...

Answer (score 1):

You have only created the one `locationslist`, so all of the `locationslist.append()` calls modify that list.  You append the same `locationslist` to as many tuples in `thedictionary` as you have elements in `userword`.  You should create one location list for each element of `userword`.

The algorithm you have could be written as a nested set of list comprehensions, which would lead to the correct lists being created:

```
user_word = ['the', 'a']
word_list = ([(uw, 
               [position for position, item in enumerate(file_contents) 
                if item == uw]) 
               for uw in user_word], 
             'Sample1')
```

That would still call `enumerate(file_contents)` once for each item in `user_word`, which could be expensive if `file_contents` is large.

I suggest you rewrite this to pass over `file_contents` once, check the item at each position against the contents of `user_word`, and append the position to only the list for the particular user_word found at that position.  I would suggest using a dictionary to keep the user_word lists separate and accessible:

```
document = 'Sample1'

temp_dict = dict((uw, []) for uw in user_word)

for position, item in enumerate(file_contents):

if item in temp_dict:
    temp_dict[item].append(position)

wordlist = ([(uw, temp_dict[uw]) for uw in user_word], document)
```

Either solution will get you the positions of each user_word, in order of appearance, in the document being scanned.  It will also return the list structure you're looking for.